# How do I get round corners for a Container?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I tried to build a `card` with round corners. I tried to add the `borderRadius` in the `Container` and the child of the `Container` is an image, but I don´t get the round corners. I only get them when I delete the `Image` property. What is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80)),
  ),
  child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
Container(
  clipBehavior : Clip.antiAlias,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80)),
  ),
  child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```

Solution 2:

```
Container(
  clipBehavior : Clip.antiAlias,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle
  ),
  child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```

Solution 3:

```
Material(
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```

Solution 4:

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the class `ClipRRect` which clips your edges to the desire radius:

```
child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80)),
       ),
       child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80)),
        child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need `Container`'s `decoration` is for clipping, you should use `CircleAvatar`

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/Bild1.jpg'),
  radius: 80,
)
```

or simply replace `Container` with `ClipRRect`

```
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(80)),
  child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```

or use `ClipOval`

```
ClipOval(
  child: Image.asset('images/Bild1.jpg'),
)
```